# Laravel: Resolving Objects from the IoC Container

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container

In `yoyo.php`:

```
class Yoyo {
    public $data;
}
```

In `global.php`:

```
App::singleton('yoyo', function()
{
    return new Yoyo;
});
```

In `filters.php`:

```
$a= App::make('yoyo');
$a->data = 'yep';
```

In a controller:

```
public function doSomething() {
    dd(App::make('yoyo'));
}
```

In `filters.php`, I can access the `data` property and it has the expected value.

In the controller, the `dd` helper shows that the `data` property is `null`.

The filter is executed before the controller method is called.

Why is `$data` `null`?

Comment: I determined that if I initialize $data in the class, then that value shows instead of null. So I;m getting a new instance of the class. Does the class have to be written as a singleton or is laravel taking care of that for me?

Comment: Alright complete mistake on my part. There was a redirect so the controller was in fact acting on a new request, one that did not initialize yoyo.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how Laravel loads files. First `filters.php` is executed and then `global.php` so first you create normal object and then singleton. If you move:

```
$a= App::make('yoyo');
$a->data = 'yep';
```

to `global.php` after creating singleton, you will get result as expected:

> object(Yoyo)#247 (1) { ["data"]=> string(3) "yep" }

Comment: Thanks but see my comment. The use of the object actually occurred in the second request and that object was not initialize for it.

Comment: @user44021 As I said this is because you use `App:make('yoyo')` BEFORE running Singleton. In this case you create simple object and it doesn't work as Singleton. You need to set any value AFTER you use `App::singleton`. As I said you need to move this code to `global.php` to make it working as you expect

Comment: @user44021 Now I see. You should use @ with someone name to notify him about comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alright complete mistake on my part. There was a redirect so the controller was in fact acting on a new request, one that did not initialize yoyo.